# Issue with MIUI (Xiaomi) marshmallow Dynamic Permissions

Tags: android

MIUI has a very weird issue related to Permissions, Pre Marshmallow the Device had the concept of Dynamic Permissions,which was good, we can simply call the method and OS took care of showing Alert for user to grant permission.
But Once the OS is Updated to Marshmallow it has issue displaying its custom Permission alert for some types **(FILE_LOCATION)** but not for all **(CAMERA)** ,

what I observed ,when I call

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(startActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
```

this

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult()
```

Is being triggered even without User's selection with Result **PERMISSION_GRANTED**.

The real problem is not just that, I tried with many apps that was downloaded from PlayStore but they did not have any issue displaying the alert when location service is needed,

So is there any work around which can trigger the Dynamic permission in all cases regardless of device

Comment: "OS took care of showing Alert for user to grant permission". How to show this alert again after a previous selection?

Comment: @Johnny this is not in our control, since that device ve not provided any API fr us

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed with the latest MIUI Rom update 6.4.14